# I'm losing the association of an error to a form field in Symfony2

Tags: php, ajax, doctrine-orm, symfony

My validation looks like

```
Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User:
    constraints:
        - \Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity: { fields:username, message: "Username already in use" }
        - \Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity: { fields:email, message: "Email address already in use" }
    properties:
        username:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - MinLength: { limit: 2, message: "Your username must have at least {{ limit }} characters." }
        email:
            - Email:
                message: The email "{{ value }}" is not a valid email.
                checkMX: true
```

My controller like:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new RegistrationType());
$form->bindRequest($request);
if ($form->isValid()) {
    //... save to db
}else{
    $errors = $form->getErrors();
    //... pass the errors back as json
}
```

I'm trying to build a user registration controller that is submitted via ajax request. However, when errors in validation are triggered, the `$error` variable looks like:

```
[2011-11-07 19:19:44] app.INFO: array (
  0 => 
  Symfony\Component\Form\FormError::__set_state(array(
     'messageTemplate' => 'Email address already in use',
     'messageParameters' => 
    array (
    ),
  )),
  1 => 
  Symfony\Component\Form\FormError::__set_state(array(
     'messageTemplate' => 'Your username must have at least {{ limit }} characters.',
     'messageParameters' => 
    array (
      '{{ value }}' => '1',
      '{{ limit }}' => 2,
    ),
  )),
) [] []
```

The problem is I have no idea which field that error corresponds to. Is there some way to find that data so that when I send the json response, I can associate the error message with the relevant field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you can query each field individually for instance:

`$form->get('username')->getErrors()`

So you could build up an array that way:

```
$errors['username'] = $form->get('username')->getErrors();
$errors['email'] = $form->get('email')->getErrors();
```

You may be able to automate things though:

```
$fields = $form->getChildren();
foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
    $errors[$field->getName()] = $field->getErrors();
}
```

I think that the `getName` function should return the field name when called on children of the form its self. Someone else may have a more efficient way though...

Comment: Using ```$form->getErrors()``` returns the errors, however ```$form->get('username')->getErrors()``` returns no errors even though the same data is submitted. It's as though errors are associated with the form in general, rather than with each field.

Comment: Yes, for example ```$builder->add('username','text', array('error_bubbling'=>true));```

Comment: Disable error bubbling. Basically a form has errors for its self as a whole, and errors for its child fields, error bubbling makes all errors for fields go to the top level (the form). Once you've disabled error bubbling you can re-test `$form->getErrors()` to see if it gives you the associative array you are looking for, otherwise my solution above should work. `$builder->add('username','text');`

Comment: instead of $form->getChildren() use $form->all(), it worked for me

Answer (score 4):

I think the accepted answer is already outdated, there's no `getChildren()` method any more.

```
$errors = [];
foreach ($form->all() as $field) {
    if ($field->getErrors()->count() > 0) {
        $fieldName = $field->getName();
        $errors[$fieldName] = [];
        foreach ($field->getErrors() as $error) {
            $errors[$fieldName][] = $error->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Eventually, if you wanted to access form fields from generated `FormView` which would give you full input field names:

```
$errors = [];
foreach ($form->createView()->children as $field) {
    if ($field->vars['errors']->count() > 0) {
        $fieldName = $field->vars['full_name'];
        $errors[$fieldName] = [];
        foreach ($field->vars['errors'] as $error) {
            $errors[$fieldName][] = $error->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```